# Word, AppleScript - "update link format" working with inline shapes?

Tags: macos, ms-word, applescript

Has anyone had any success issuing an "update" in AppleScript when interacting with inline shapes Word 2011?

I've got the following chunk of code (mostly swiped from the Mac Office 2004 AppleScript reference):

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    repeat with aShape in (get inline shapes of active document)
        if auto update of link format of aShape is false then
            update link format of aShape
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

As far as I gather, this just gets the inline shapes and for those where auto-update is set to false, it says "update the shape from the link."

I insert an image, making sure to link it to the file (let's say `"/Users/me/Documents/myfile.png"`). If I ask Word to "give me a list of inline shapes and their paths" in AppleScript I see `"/Users/me/Documents/myfile.png"`. OK, cool.

Then I run the code.

Couple of things happen:

1. `auto update` says its value is missing - I have to check `missing
   value` which seems really wrong. I gather it's supposed to be a BOOL, but... it's just nil.
2. If I check against missing value
   and just ignore it (which may part of my problem) and I run `update link format` on the shape, the shape's path is completely *removed*.
   So at this point my shape path is totally gone - forever. The image is still in the document, but the path / link has been nulled out.

I have to assume I'm doing something wrong here.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to `update link format` correctly?

Thank you in advance

Note: I'm writing a Cocoa app and am opting to try to incorporate the AppleScript approach because the general "update" method for the Obj-C application object seemed to accept an enum and not the actual object... and it also didn't seem to do anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I do not think you are doing anything wrong but I believe it takes a trick to make this stuff work, and I am not completely sure about that. The explanation is in any case too long for a comment.

As a general observation, in Word you tend to get `missing value` in cases where the property is not relevant in that case. So I think if you have a picture which does not have any link, `link format of aShape` will return `missing value`.

Any shape which has a link should have a `link format` that is *not* a `missing value`. But AFAIK `auto update` is only applicable to inline shapes that are links to OLE Objects, in which case the value of `auto update` can be `true` or `false`, but for images that are not OLE links, `auto update` will be `missing value`.

(In earlier versions of Word, roughly speaking an image that was *linked* was represented by a field code. If it was linked via OLE, the field type would be { LINK }. Otherwise, if it was just a link to a picture file, the field type would be { INCLUDEPICTURE }. In recent versions of Word, the handling of graphics has changed, more than once, and you typically only see these field codes if you insert them yourself, or if you save a document as a .doc rather than a .docx)

So perhaps one thing you need to do is check the `inline shape type` of the `inline shape` and adjust the processing depending on the type.

AFAIK if you have a linked OLE object, then using `update link format` should work. But if it's a link to a picture file, it doesn't. what does appear to work is to set the full name of the picture to itself, e.g.

```
set source full name of link format of aShape to source full name of link format of aShape
```

Except that the result of that is actually to replace the picture by a box with a message. But repeating the command does appear actually to update the link, i.e.

```
set source full name of link format of aShape to source full name of link format of aShape
set source full name of link format of aShape to source full name of link format of aShape
```

Comment: Wow - _thank you_. I don't know how the heck you figured that one out. Updating the path twice will get it to apply... I really appreciate the explanation on the OLE/image differences - helps me understand a bit more about not only "missing value" but its relationship to some of the other things I've seen in the AppleScript objects. My other take-away is "don't trust the docs." They explicitly list the paths / source full name properties as read-only and yet - the path was just updated. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: Yes, a big problem in this area is that the docs have never been updated since the 2004 version, as you discovered I think.

Comment: I showed a few other people the "link update doesn't take the first time? try it twice" example and I think our collective minds were blown. I would never have tried that...

Comment: I,m pretty sure I discovered this approach by accident :-)